# Finding a Struts plug-in for Eclipse Keplere

Tags: struts2, struts-1

I want to install Struts (1.x and 2.x) plug-ins for Eclipse (Kepler). Could anybody recommend one?

Thanks.

Comment: [StrutsClipse](https://github.com/aleksandr-m/strutsclipse).